# How to draw unfilled box in python?

Tags: python

```
w=int(input('Width: '))

product=('*')

print(product * w)

for i in range(w-2):

    print(product,(w-4) * (' '),product)

print(product * w)
```

the program is working fine for w>4 but for <3 it's not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `,` that automatically adds a space to the string. That is why you had to use (w-4) if you dont add the two spaces by `,` then (w-2) is enough.

Switch your line to this, and then it works for 3 too:

```
print(product+(w-2) * (' ')+product)
```

Comment: if i want to add a diagonal in this square, what should i further add in this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you put w < 4 , in the line

```
 print(product,(w-4) * (' '),product)
```

(w-4) will be negative, and

```
-ve*(' ') does not make any sense.
```

so it does not work for values less than 4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not strictly true. Python evaluates `-value*'string'` to `''` (the empty string).